# AWS Cross account shared AMI tags not showing up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have a setup using two accounts in AWS, A and B.
CI builds and tags AMIs in A and than shares them with B.

I just notice that none of the tags created in A show up in B.

Is this expected behaviour?

There is nothing on the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tags are always private.

> You can tag public or shared resources, but the tags you assign are available only to your AWS account and not to the other accounts sharing the resource.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-restrictions